# Deleting item with a many-to-many relation within it

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a model contains a list of the same model as a many-to-many relationship, and I have a problem when deleting an item of this model type when having a relation with another item.

This error happened because of a foreign key error.

The model code is as the following:

```
public class Employee : ModelBase
{
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Employee> Managers { get; set; }

}
```

The mapping file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Models"
                   namespace="Models"
                   default-lazy="false">
  <class name="Employee">
    <id name ="Id">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property name="FullName"></property>

    <bag name="Managers">
      <key column="Id" />
      <many-to-many class="Employee"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Suppose I have created two employees, emp1, emp2, and then I have added emp2 to Managers list in emp1.

If I want to delete emp1, I have the same error, but I can easily resolve it by clearing the managers list. but if I want to delete emp2, I cannot loop for every employee to see if the Managers list contains this employee!! it will reduce the performance.

My Question, is there an implicit way for nhibernate to handle this issue?

**EDIT1 :**

My delete statement is

```
var queryString = string.Format("delete {0} where Id = :id",
    typeof(T));
session.CreateQuery(queryString)
    .SetParameter("id", modelId)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, either we've got here the *parent-child* hierarchy, (x)or *many-to-many* relation.

I. In case of many-to-many, we are missing

- the pairing table
- the second, reverted view on this relationship.

The model we have is providing the up view: `Managers`, and should also provide the down view: `Subordinates`.

```
<bag name="Managers" table="ManagerSubOrdinates" >
  <key column="ManagerId" />
  <many-to-many class="Employee" column="SubordinateId"/>
</bag>

<bag name="Subordinates" table="ManagerSubOrdinates" inverse="true" >
  <key column="SubordinateId" />
  <many-to-many class="Employee" column="ManagerId"/>
</bag>
```

Now, we mapped both ends of the pairing table/relation `ManagerSubOrdinates`. If we will delete the Employee, the related records will be removed as well - but just from the pairing table. Not the related Managers or Subordinates

Finally the Deletion.

Now, when we do have the mapping in place, the correct way how to delete is like this

```
// load the Employee with ID == 1 into the ISession
var employee = session.Get<Employee>(1); // id 1
// pass this instance into the Delete 
session.Delete(employee);
```

This will instruct NHibernate to properly remove all records from pairing table (both mappings) and then delete the Employee record itself

(not sure here) II. If this is in fact, the *parent-child* relation, we have to correct the mapping this way:

```
<bag name="Subordinates">
  <key column="ManagerId" />
  <many-to-many class="Employee"/>
</bag>
<many-to-one class="Employee" Name="Manager" column="ManagerId" >
```

Here I am just guessing (more Subordinates, one Manager), but The **essence is in the column name** `ManagerId`. In most scenarios, the `key` column does not have value **"Id"** which usually referes to the table `Primary` key, not the foreign key...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try the first solution and tell what happened. However, I am not sure if the second solution fits the problem, since we are not addressing only direct managers, we also consider the HR as manager for every body, so we may add them to every employee ...

Comment: I am not challenging your business model, the domain. No, Never! ;) I am just trying to point out how the mapping in NHibernate is working and what we have to do in each of the above scenarios. To make it working, regardless what the business needs ;)

Comment: yeah sure :), I am not saying that, I also have not said any thing about our business. I have a question here, if we add an employee in the Managers list, will we have him in the Subordinates list in the manager automatically or we should add him using code? I think "inverse" will do the job, but I want to be sure :)

Comment: Yes, we will. but there are some buts: We have to relaod that Employee ... other words, to allow NHibernate to fill all relations during the loading from DB. If we do have all the instances in the memory/C# runtime, NHibernate won't do anything. BUT this should not be usually the issue. Because we should have one operation/session/web request ... for writing... the second for reading. During the expost reading, we should have all the stuff filled properly

Comment: If that helped, great. Enjoy NHibernate. It is amazing tool, with awesome abilities ... ;)

Comment: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK96A74FB033B9EF46". The conflict occurred in database "Vacations", table "dbo.ManagerSubOrdinates", column 'SubordinateId'.
The statement has been terminated. .... :(

Comment: Vacations is the name of the database, and the database is empty, with no entries other than two employees, and the relation between them the the table ManagerSubOrdinates.

Comment: Well, this is weird. Could you please, show your mapping. The `many-to-many` relation is working really well in NHibernate. It - when the root entity (Employee) is deleted, automatically ... firstly removes all the related records from many-to-many table. AUTOMATICALLY... no special setting.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't understand you, "Could you please, show your mapping", "firstly removes all the related records from many-to-many table. AUTOMATICALLY... no special setting"

Comment: Sorry I've got it! Sorry ... needed coffee ;) Well: We need to work more standard way. If we want to delete some item, we should load it into session: `var employee = session.Get<Employee>(1)`. Having this reference in the session, we can call `session.Delete(employee)`. Now, NHibernate will correctly check all the records in the many-to-many relation tables... delete them first, and then the Employee instance itself. Please, try this ;)

Comment: I have listed the way I delete Items in the question, is it good?

Comment: I would say, that this is causing the issues, with foreign keys. I would strongly suggest, do the deletion as I commented above. Load the object into the session by ID, call Delete(instance) ... see http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-deleting

Comment: Ufff ;) great to see that. NHibernate is not as easy to get into. But please, keep on, do not give up. NHibernate will gift you later ;)

Comment: I have used my implementation of the mapping, but only replaced the delete method as you told me, and it works fine, please post this as the solution in another answer post. and thanks a lot for you, that helped me a lot in saving too much work. Thank you very much :)

Comment: please for anyone who have the same problem, please post the modification on the delete as a new answer to this question so I will be able to mark it as the required answer, so others will not have to read all this comments log. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the Deletion snippet. That should work for anyone else in the future ;)